# generate lots of random numbers in small time interval(c++)

Tags: c++, random

I have a for loop, and inside it I'm generating random numbers and seeding it with `time(msecs)`,but it's not generatin them randomly, what can I do to solve that?

note:
I know why rand() is not generating them randomly, I'm asking for the solution, and I'm using Qt creator if that will help.

```
for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
       qsrand(QDateTime::currentDateTime().time().msec());//for every j itteratio i must
       for(int i=1;i<s;i++){                              //have new sequence and ret is 
        ret.push_back(rand()%s);                          //vector i'm using Qt 
        }                                                 //s=4 for now,but s=[1;50]
      qDebug()<<"new sequence ...";
    }
```

it generates
[2,1,1],[2,1,1],[2,1,1],[2,1,1],[2,1,1];

Comment: You will never get trully randomness off a machine. Also you should seed it once, not with every iteration.

Comment: What do you mean it is not generating them randomly?  Do you mean it always gives you the same sequence of numbers?  Do you mean it always gives you the same number?  The time it takes to generate a random number is less than milliseconds, so you are probably seeding it with the same number a lot of the time (seed outside the loop!).

Comment: From the code you posted, I conclude that the problem is because of a mistake.

Comment: Please post your code and explain quite what you mean by "not generating them randomly".

Comment: Seed once, and tell us what `s` is.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `qsrand` but not `qrand`?

Comment: @ Retired Ninjano,there is no reason at all,i'm just using Qt creator so i'm using thier implimentaion

Comment: Except you're not, If you use one of their functions to seed and then a function that isn't theirs to get the random numbers can you see where that might not work?  Besides, based on your numbers you're generating 15 numbers, most likely all within the same millisecond, so you can see why each sequence might be exactly the same because the seed is the same.

Comment: @ Retired Ninjano,yes i know that i am seeding with same number,i was looking for the solution,but thanks for your concern

Answer (score 0):

Depends of what is you application. 
If you need to generate secure random numbers that can't be guessed, then you should use CSPRNG https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator. 
For this purpouse there is  /dev/urandom availabe for unix clones.

In case you need random numbers for simulation or something similar where you need random numbers you should use high quality super fast, random and large  PRNG called mersenne twister.
It is available in standard library of c++11 or in boost. (headers only)
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_random.html

As many other said, make sure you seed only once.

Comment: i will definitely check them

Answer (score 0):

If you want a long sequence of random numbers, like here, then you probably want to use a pseudo-random number generator (unless this is for cryptography!). C++11 brought support for random and pseudo-random numbers into the standard library, which makes it very easy to use. Just seed the PRNG with a true random number before the loop, then just use the output from that to get (pseudo-)random numbers. You will also need to include the `random` header.

```
std::random_device rd;
std::default_random_engine e1{rd()};
std::cout << e1(); // random number
std::cout << e1(); // another random number

std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist{1, 6};
std::cout << dist(e1); // random integer between 1 and 6
```

If this is for cryptographical uses, see what Luka Rahne said.